# How to fix this possibly the simplest code to search a record in mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a mysql database running on localhost which contains a table "detail" where I want to search for "code" and return the value of "location" to a text box. i have written the following code in visual studio vb.net,

```
    Private Sub BTN_SEARCH_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_SEARCH.Click
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test;user=root;password=12345")
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand("select location from detail where code = @code", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tb_CODE.Text
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    tb_LOCATION.Text = ""
    If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
        tb_LOCATION.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("NO Data Found")
    End If
End Sub
```

i get errors at

> adapter.Fill(table)

and

> tb_LOCATION.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()

depending on my input string, which I'm puzzled.
The table has 8 columns but I only want to retrieve data from location column which is column 3. the search code is in column 1.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please never post on stack overflow saying "I got an error message" without saying exactly what that error message is

Answer (score 2):

You state your parameter is of type Int, but you set it to a string. I know that VB is a bit care free when it comes to these these but it always wise to be specific

```
command.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(tb_CODE.Text);
```

I'd advocate setting `Option Strict On` and getting used to programming without the "help" of implicit type conversions (not that this would have helped here, because parameter.Vakie takes an Object)

For accessing columns, using names is better than numbers:

```
    tb_LOCATION.Text = table.Rows(0)("location").ToString()
```

Then it doesn't matter where your column is

As an aside, as you're only selecting one column here, and I think you're saying "code" is the primary key, you could have just used

```
tb_LOCATION.Text = Convert.ToString(mysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar())
```

And dispense with the adapter, DataTable etc - use them if you're downloading many column/rows, use executescalar for queries that returns single value (a result set that's 1 row by 1 column)

Answer (score 1):

`tb_LOCATION.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()` cuz you have only one field so you need change to `table.Rows(0)(0).ToString()`

Comment: yes, you right)Thank you for information i gave upvote

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is with this line...

```
command.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tb_CODE.Text
```

You are using MySQL but have referenced an Sql server type.

I have added Using blocks to ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed event if there is an error. I also added a try parse on the user input. Never trust a user :-).

Since you are only looking for a single value you can use .ExecuteScalar which returns the first column of the first row of the result set.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim code As Integer
    If Not Int32.TryParse(tb_CODE.Text, code) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in the Code box")
        Return
    End If
    Dim location As Object = Nothing
    Using connection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test;user=root;password=12345")
        Using command As New MySqlCommand("select location from detail where code = @code", connection)
            command.Parameters.Add("@code", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = code
            location = command.ExecuteScalar()
        End Using
    End Using
    If location Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("NO Data Found")
        Return
    End If
    tb_LOCATION.Text = location.ToString
End Sub
```